# python ArgParse custom action with key value options using metavar causes duplicates in -h output

Tags: python, dictionary, argparse

I'm using a custom action for argument parser to allow key=value options for specific arguments.

```
test.py --arg2 input1=something input2=something_else
```

The custom action works fine, but when I use metavar to list all of the custom options, I get duplicates.

Here is my custom action:

```
class KeyValue(argparse.Action):
def __call__(self, parser, namespace,
             values, option_string=None):
    setattr(namespace, self.dest, dict())

    for value in values:
        # split it into key and value
        key, value = value.split('=')
        # assign into dictionary
        getattr(namespace, self.dest)[key] = value
```

Here is the utilization:

```
    sub_1.add_argument(
        "--arg2",
        action=KeyValue,
        nargs="*",
        default=NoArgumentProvided(),
        help='arg 2 help',
        metavar="key1=val1 key2=val2"
    )
```

What the help looks like, with duplicates showing up:

```
usage: arg_issue.py test [-h] [--arg1]
                     [--arg2 [key1=val1 key2=val2 [key1=val1 key2=val2 ...]]]

test description

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --arg1                arg1 help
  --arg2 [key1=val1 key2=val2 [key1=val1 key2=val2 ...]]
                        arg 2 help
```

Any ideas why I'm getting duplicates?  It's clearly from the custom Action, but I'm not sure why?

Full Code:

```
import argparse


class NoArgumentProvided(object):
    pass


class KeyValue(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace,
                 values, option_string=None):
        setattr(namespace, self.dest, dict())

        for value in values:
            # split it into key and value
            key, value = value.split('=')
            # assign into dictionary
            getattr(namespace, self.dest)[key] = value


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description='parser',
        formatter_class=argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter,
    )

    # top-level args.
    parser.add_argument('--verbose',
                        help='Verbose mode',
                        action='store_true',
                        required=False,
                        default=NoArgumentProvided())
    # Add the main sub parsers
    subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='action')

    sub_1 = subparsers.add_parser(
        'test',
        help='test help',
        description='test description')

    sub_1.add_argument(
        "--arg1",
        action='store_true',
        required=False,
        default=NoArgumentProvided(),
        help='arg1 help'
    )

    sub_1.add_argument(
        "--arg2",
        action=KeyValue,
        nargs="*",
        default=NoArgumentProvided(),
        help='arg 2 help',
        metavar="key1=val1 key2=val2"
    )

    subparsers.required = True

    args = parser.parse_args()


if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the metavar is a tuple of strings

```
p.add_argument('--foo', nargs='*', metavar=('one','two'))
```

the help will be

```
usage: ipython3 [-h] [--foo [one [two ...]]]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --foo [one [two ...]]
```

With `nargs='*'`, the usage is 2 parts, `[one [two ...]]`.  Use of a custom action class doesn't change that display.

Keep the `metavar` simple, and elaborate in the `help` as needed.  `description` can also add details.

### edit

A patch a couple of years ago has simplified the `*` help.

https://bugs.python.org/issue38438
argparse "usage" overly-complex with nargs="*"

With Python 3.10

```
In [218]: import argparse310 as argparse
In [219]: p=argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [220]: p.add_argument('--foo',nargs='*');
In [221]: p.print_help()
usage: ipython3 [-h] [--foo [FOO ...]]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help       show this help message and exit
  --foo [FOO ...]
```

The tuple version is still available:

```
In [226]: p._actions[1].metavar=('one','two')
In [227]: p.print_help()
usage: ipython3 [-h] [--foo [one [two ...]]]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --foo [one [two ...]]
```

Comment: Interesting; using a tuple for the metavar works (better).  I don't understand why I get the duplicates when metavar is a string, unless something inside argparse is trying to guess and break it apart.  Anyway, thanks!

Comment: If metavar is a string the display is `--foo [metavar [metavar ...]]`

Comment: are you saying that it's not duplicating it when a string is used?  That's exactly the problem I was seeing. I should mention this is 2.7...giving this string metavar `metavar="key1=val1 key2=val2"` when I see the help, its shown double.  Check the full code.
`--arg2 [key1=val1 key2=val2 [key1=val1 key2=val2 ...]]`
See the duplication there?  I'm guessing this is expected?  Also, in combo with nargs="*" I can only give exactly 2 items when metavar is a tuple.

Comment: See my edit for the simpler display that is used in the recent Python version.  Python 2.7 is not receiving this kind of patches.  (My default argparse is still 3.8).